# Uploading and running Gensim model for data augmentation

Tags: python, gensim

I am trying to follow this example https://github.com/dsfsi/textaugment to upload a pre-trained Gensim model for data augmentation

```
    import textaugment
    import gensim
    from textaugment import Word2vec
    model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(r'\GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
    from textaugment import Word2vec
    t = Word2vec(model)
    t.augment('The stories are good')
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

at line

```
t = Word2vec(model)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

If you edit your question to include the full error message shown, including the traceback identifying exact files/lines-of-code leading to the error, it will often provide extra important info to know what's going wrong. (Whenever possible, show answerers all the text/output that you see, not just excerpts.)

But also, the examples at the page you link, https://github.com/dsfsi/textaugment, all show the `model` passed in as a named parameter (`model=SOMETHING`), not merely a positional parameter. You should try to do it the same way (and here I've changed the name of your local variabe to make it more distinct from the parameter-name, and removed the out-of-place `r` prefix):

```
my_model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('\GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
t = Word2vec(model=my_model)
```

The error you got may be less confusing once you know, from experience or careful viewing of the traceback, that the call to the constructor `Word2vec()` actually calls another method, `__init__()`, behind the scenes. And that `__init__()` method receives both the newly-created instance, **and** whatever else you supplied, as 'positional' arguments. That is: 2 positional arguments, when it normally only expects 1 (the new instances), with any extra arguments as *named* arguments (`model=SOMETHING` style).

Comment: I pass a named argument, which textaugment says can be a model object or a filepath to the .model file, and I get the same error. I don't think it's a matter of passed named vs positional argument here

Comment: As with the person who reported a similar error about 19 months ago, the most helpful information would be a full error message, including tracebacks. As you can't edit your error into their question, I'd suggest asking a new question, with the full details of your code attempts, and error message(s) received.